# Union of n-ary cartesian powers of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, exponentiation

Given a set $S$, is there a name for the following:

$$f(S,N) = \bigcup\limits_{k=0}^{N}S^{k}$$

For example for $S=\{x, y, z\}$ and $N=2$ the result would be:
$$\{(), (x), (y), (z), (x, x), (x,y), (x, z), (y, x), (y, y), (y, z), (z, x), (z,y), (z,z)\}$$

Is there any way to relate it to a notion/terminology in mathematics?

Comment: I think strings of length at most $k$ on $S$, would be the terminology.

Comment: Similar to what Punga wrote, I would say "$f(S, N)$ is the set of all strings with length at most $N$ over alphabet $S$". Also, I would write $f(S, N) = S^{\le N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is standard to denote this set by $S^{\leq N}$.

It is always best to explain the notation you use in words (as Punga suggests in the comments) the first time you use it, especially if it is less familiar.

The set of *all* finite sequences from $S$, with no bound on their length, is written $S^{<\omega}$ or $S^*$. The first notation is used (among others) by set theorists - here $\omega$ is the least infinite [ordinal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). The second notation is used (among others) by computer scientists - here $^*$ is the [Kleene star](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

Comment: And how a mathematician would call $S^{\leq N}$ using words (in a concise and clear manner)? (the context is that I am implementing such a function in a software library and I want to give it a name).

Comment: "The set of all sequences from $S$ of length at most $N$" @Vincent